# Android: Splashscreen is blurry and has rounded corners

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I have implemented a splashscreen into my app using this link: [The Best Way to Create a Splashscreen in Android](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-best-way-to-create-a-splash-screen-in-android-16f9096bf827). It works fine, but the image is extremely blurry and has rounded corners with a black background - basically, it's very unprofessional looking.
Here's the code from my launch_screen.xml file, which is in my drawable folder:

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">

        <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

        <item>
            <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/splashlogo"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

And here is the code from my styles.xml file, where I create a new theme using this launch_screen.xml file:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
```

I know I could create a splashscreen using a timed activity, but I like how this method shows the splashscreen when the rest of the app is loading (my app is very slow to start up for some reason).

Can anyone help me improve the appearance of my splashscreen? I just want it to show up as a normal image that takes up the full screen and is of high quality.

**EDIT** so I changed my file to a vector asset,but now nothing shows up, just a black screen. See code below:

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">

        <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_splashscreen2"
            android:gravity="center"
        />

    </layer-list>
```

Comment: Add sufficiently-high resolution bitmap drawables to your resources. Or better yet; use vector drawables.

Comment: @Michael thanks for your response.. How do I ensure they are high resolution?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp

Comment: @Michael I changed the file to a Vector asset and changed my code to accommodate this (edited question to show this), but now the splashscreen does not appear at all. Just a black screen. Any idea why/?

Comment: This problem with Android devices comes from the fact that their screen sizes *vary a lot* and there may not be a `splashscreen` image from the **pre-defined sizes** that exactly fits the given screen. In such a case, the image is resized to fit the screen, which may result in a distorted or blurred splash screen. So... make sure your image statistics (height, width, density ...) are not *so far off* the screen size you want, that the *distortion* is noticeable. Vectors are  infinitely scalable, unlike bitmaps.